# Dialog activity - text gets cut in android

Tags: android, android-xml

I am trying a simple contacts app that displays all the phones etc. When I click on the contact name, it displays the contact numbers in a dialogue activity. I can see the name and numbers properly when I have less numbers.. But if I have more numbers the name part in the activity gets cut.. Please check the below screen shot.

Can you see that Joe David text and profile picture gets cut. The numbers are displayed properly as it is in listview hence I can scroll down or up to view all the numbers.

How to fix this? - This screen shot is from Nexus 5 but same on Nexus 4 / Galaxy nexus too.. I have tried it on these.. Not sure on other phones..

XML Details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutContactNumber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:background="@drawable/blackbg"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.res.dese.number.ResizableImageView
        android:id="@+id/CImage"
        android:layout_width="120px"
        android:layout_height="120px"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/no_pic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PhoneLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textColor="#2CABE2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/whiteline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/whiteline" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".65"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#007FFF"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/whiteline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/whiteline" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".15"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/okandeditlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/editContactlinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="2dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/editnumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/newedit" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDeleteConatct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/del"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/newdelete" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screen shot of issue]

Thanks!

Comment: Updated the question with XML details.. Thanks!

Comment: Anybody who can help me out with please?

Comment: Did you hide the header of the dialog box?..

Comment: @icaneatclouds Didn't get you?

Comment: Its maybe because of your code in hiding the dialog box header. Can you post your code in calling that Dialog box?

Comment: use scrollView as ur top most view it resolve ur issue, Dialog activity almost covery the region availbale in ur screen for dialog activity.

Comment: @icaneatclouds - This is a dialog activity and not a customized dialog.

Comment: give proper weight and u have used too many unnecessary layout

Comment: @CoolMonster - I tried what you told me. I get force a close.

Comment: @kaushik - I require those layouts orelse it doesn't show up properly in few phones or can you please suggest the best? I can try it out.

Comment: @TheDevMan : check my answer if it works for u

Comment: What error u received while tiring my method.

Comment: I guess a distribution of layout weight as 2 6 2 should work.

Comment: and a little marginTop to your outermost linear layout as when shown as a dialog it is cutting off the upper edge.

Comment: which theme you had applied?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got the XML, fixed.

Comment: then mark the answer as accepted are else post your valid xml and post proper comment to it. it will helpful for other who view your question

Answer (score 6):

Give a try with this `layout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <com.res.dese.number.ResizableImageView
            android:id="@+id/CImage"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/no_pic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PhoneLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="XXX"
            android:textColor="#2CABE2"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/whiteline" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="12" >
    </ListView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/whiteline" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/editnumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/newedit" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/del"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/newdelete" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Instead of [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) you can use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes to your given code. Everything looks fine now!

Comment: So, @TheDevMan shouldn't you grant him the bounty? :)

Comment: @kaushik sorry for the delay! Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what exactly was causing the problem? I can't really tell by looking at the xml

Comment: @Gak2 : giving `proper weight` and instead of `px` use `dp` **density-pixel** that is the solution

Answer (score 2):

Give this property to listview

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#007FFF"
    android:dividerHeight="3dp" >
</ListView>
```

And remove other weight from other all the views and set height as wrap_content so listview will get remaining area after that all elements will set properly.

if you give

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

to element than it will occupy only remaining area.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PhoneLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="XXX"
    android:textColor="#2CABE2"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

use:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PhoneLabel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="XXX"
    android:textColor="#2CABE2"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try.
Put this in your **styles.xml:**

```
  <style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

Lets say you have your **dialogxml.xml** now. So here is the code for calling the dialog:

```
public void openDialog() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getLayoutInflater();

        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogxml, null);

        // Build the dialog
        Dialog dialogBuilder = new Dialog(this, R.style.CustomDialog);
        dialogBuilder.setContentView(customView);


        dialogBuilder.show();
    }
```

Give it a try and tell me if it didn't work. :)

Comment: This is a dialog activity and not a customized dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your activity code also. Will edit my answer then.

An option is to use `getWindow()` and use its setLayout, setMargin and more...

```
 //after setContentView, set the Layout parameters to fill parent (should make the dialog full screen)
    getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

I have used the properties from `getWindow()` and set margins, provide padding and position, alignment for my Dialog Activity.

Another option is adding some `padding` (through values in res `dimens` xml) to your parent layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to the listview `android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutContactNumber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:background="@drawable/blackbg"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.res.dese.number.ResizableImageView
        android:id="@+id/CImage"
        android:layout_width="120px"
        android:layout_height="120px"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/no_pic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PhoneLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:freezesText="true"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="XXX"
        android:textColor="#2CABE2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/whiteline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/whiteline" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".65"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="#007FFF"
        android:marginBottiom="20dp"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/whiteline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/whiteline" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".15"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/okandeditlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/editContactlinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="2dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/editnumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/newedit" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDeleteConatct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/del"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/newdelete" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems from the fact that you are using layout_weight properties on your layouts. This way all layouts nicely shrink / expand depending on number of phone numbers, but they also won't look too good if you add even more numbers.

I would suggest that you use layout_height="wrap_content" for all horizontal LinearLayouts. Your screen elements will have a more defined height then and ListView will not be able to claim too much screen space for itself any more.